# print something when sprite is paused

Tags: skaction

what i have been trying to do is to print out something to the console whenever the timer sprite is all the way tipped at its maximum angle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom action with [customActionWithDuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:). `customActionWithDuration` executes a user-defined block of code over the duration of an action. In this case, replace the `waitAction` in your code with a custom action with a print statement in the block:

```
let waitAndPrint = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(3) {
    _, _ in
    println("tipped")
}
```

Then, modify the sequence to include the custom action

```
SKAction.sequence([waitAndPrint, rotate, waitAndPrint, rotate.reversedAction()])
```

**EDIT**

You can use the following to print roughly every second. The parameter `elapsedTime` starts at ~0.0 and is incremented by ~1/60 (i.e., the frame rate) on subsequent calls.

```
let waitAndPrint = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(3) {
    _, elapsedTime in
    // prints about every second
    if (elapsedTime % 1 < 0.018) {
        println("tipped")
    }
}
```

Comment: also do you know how to make it so it prints within one second intervals as opposed to spewing out "tapped"